# spring hibernate sql one to many relation, use controller request GET to create entry

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, orm, one-to-many

i know the title is a bit confusing, but sorry i really dont know how to shorten it properly.
ok, here is what i need. i have a 'customer' table and it has one to many relation to 'order' table
(i am using hibernate JPA by the way)

what i evetually wanna do is, i will have a spring controller, taking request GET parameters, and add data to database,   and in my DB , for each customer , it will have many orders...

and here is my code:

here is my entity tables:
customer:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer customerId;

    private String customerName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")  
    private List<Order> orderList;

    public Integer getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrderList() {
        return orderList;
    }

    public void setOrderList(List<Order> orderList) {
        this.orderList = orderList;
    }
}
```

order:

```
@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer orderId;

    private String itemCode;

    private String itemPrice;

    @ManyToOne  
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerId")  
    private Customer customer;

    public Integer getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(Integer orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getItemCode() {
        return itemCode;
    }

    public void setItemCode(String itemCode) {
        this.itemCode = itemCode;
    }

    public String getItemPrice() {
        return itemPrice;
    }

    public void setItemPrice(String itemPrice) {
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
}
```

my service interface:

```
public interface CustomerService {
    public void addCustomer(Customer customer);
    public List<Customer> listCustomers();
    public void removeCustomer(Integer customerId);
    public void updateCustomer(Customer customer);
}
```

service impl:

```
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService{

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
        em.persist(customer);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> listCustomers() {
        // read data out, will implment later
        //return null;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void removeCustomer(Integer customerId) {
        Customer customer = em.find(Customer.class, customerId);
        if (customer != null) {
            em.remove(customer);
        }

    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateCustomer(Customer customer) {
        em.merge(customer);
    }

}
```

and finally my spring controller:

```
@Controller
public class CutomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add_customer_from_ios", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String addCustomerFromIOSClient(HttpServletRequest request,
            @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer, BindingResult result) {
        Order orderone = new Order();
        orderone.setItemPrice("66");
        orderone.setItemCode("testcode1");
        orderone.setCustomer(customer);

        Order ordertwo = new Order();
        ordertwo.setItemPrice("77");
        ordertwo.setItemCode("testcode2");
        ordertwo.setCustomer(customer);

        List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();
        orderList.add(orderone);
        orderList.add(ordertwo);

        customer.setOrderList(orderList);

        customerService.addCustomer(customer);

        return "successful registreated";
    }
}
```

so when i type `localhost:8080/add_customer_from_ios?customername=testuser`  into address bar, i expect in my DB to add  something like:

customer table:

```
  customerid | customername 
    ------------+--------------
             01 |  testuser
```

order table:

```
  customerid  | orderid | itemCode  | itemPrice
 ------------+------------------------
        01     |   01    | testcode1  |  66
 ------------+------------------------
        01     |   02    | testcode2  |  77
```

but what i actually get is like this....absolutely empty nothing added....

```
 customerid | customername 
  ------------+--------------
            01 |
```

and the order table is not even created by hibernate....

[p.s  i have confident in my springconfig.xml it shouldnt be a problem, as i have many other one to one table with diff service they are all working good.. just this one to many relation doesnt work.. and it is my first time learning one to many relation here, please point me out if i ve done anything silly...  any explains with code example would be very helpful]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to binding the name correctly you need to do two things to get the orders to persist.

1 specify cascade options on the relationship

2 set both sides of the relationship

```
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer customerId;

    private String customerName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = cascadeType.ALL)  
    private List<Order> orderList;

    public Integer getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrderList() {
        //FIXME return unmodifiable list or iterator to force clients through add method.
        return orderList;
    }

    public void addOrder(Order order){
        order.setCustomer(this);
        orders.add(order);
    }
}
```

And update controller accordingly:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add_customer_from_ios", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String addCustomerFromIOSClient(HttpServletRequest request,
            @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer, BindingResult result) {
        Order orderone = new Order();
        orderone.setItemPrice("66");
        orderone.setItemCode("testcode1");

        Order ordertwo = new Order();
        ordertwo.setItemPrice("77");
        ordertwo.setItemCode("testcode2");

        customer.addOrder(orderone);
        customer.addOrder(ordertwo);

        customerService.addCustomer(customer);

        return "successful registreated";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fully match the case on properties, so your request `localhost:8080/add_customer_from_ios?customername=testuser` will not bind to the property `customerName` inside *Customer*, due to a difference in the cases. Try simply with

```
localhost:8080/add_customer_from_ios?customerName=testuser
```

Comment: may you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602318/hibernate-myinterceptoronflushdirty-is-never-called pls?